# is it right to call News.objects.all()[:x] to fetch fixed number of records

Tags: django, django-models

what i am asking:
if i need to extract top 10 newest News from db. I found only way

```
 News.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
```

but is it safe? How works this construction? Will it fetch all News records from database and then will order them and then will take only 10 pieces of them? Or it will optimize query and will take only 10 newest records from database? It is significant since I do have over 1000 News records in database and it will take long time to get them from database and even longer to sort them.

Answer (score 3):

This is safe as [QuerySets as lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). At most ten objects will be fetched in your case as the database query will be optimized to return only ten records from the database.

You can read more about [when QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) and [limiting QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) (this section deals with slicing QuerySets which is what you are doing).

Comment: thanks. i did read before both of sections but they are ambiguous. for example News.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:10] and News.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10] will do the same or not? thanks by the way